# Unable to get push notification data when app hasn't yet been launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I implemented the support for push notification and it is working like a charm. However, in one particular scenario, it doesn't give me the desired result.

When the app is running (state is either active or is in background), whenever a push notification is received, the function "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is called. BUT, when the app is terminated and a push notification is received, I believe "didReceiveRemoteNotification" NEVER gets called (can't test this scenario using Xcode as app hasn't been launched yet). This prevents me from loading a particular view controller to the user.

Can someone please tell me how I can get the data corresponding to the push notification when received while the app hasn't been launched yet? Is there some other function that I need to look into for this particular scenario ONLY?

Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:):

> If the app is not running when a push notification arrives, the method
>   launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the
>   launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle
>   that push notification. Instead, your implementation of the
>   `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method needs to get the
>   push notification payload data and respond appropriately.

In particular, the key you should be looking for in the launch options dictionary is `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`.